# what type i should declare for image

Tags: flutter, dart

What type should I declare for image since i want image 2 is an option but it keep display an error when I want to call it on my body. can someone resolve it for me. thank you

```
body: SingleChildScrollView( 
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(4.0),
          child: Column( 
            children: [ 
              TypePercentage(
                title: 'Percentage according to\nnationality', 
                image: "assets/images/circle.png",
                //image: "",
                value: "35%", 
                subtitle: "Users are\nMen"
                ),
                TypePercentage(
                title: 'Percentage according to\nnationality', 
                // image: "assets/images/circle.png", 
                // image2: "assets/images/circle.png",
                value: "65%", 
                subtitle: "Users are w\nWomen"
                )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),



class TypePercentage extends StatelessWidget {

  final String title;
  final Widget image;
  final Widget? image2;
  final String value;
  final String subtitle;

   TypePercentage({ 
    Key? key, 
    required this.title, 
    required this.image, 
    this.image2, 
    required this.value, 
    required this.subtitle, 
    }) : super(key: key);
```

Comment: Q: What ... is ... the ... error?  Please [Edit] your post, and copy/paste the exact error message.

Comment: What problem are you facing exactly?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are trying to pass string to the class you can use String

```
class TypePercentage extends StatelessWidget {

  final String title;
  final String image;
  final String? image2;
  final String value;
  final String subtitle;
```

To display an image using a string you can use

```
Image.asset(imagePath), //asset image
Image.network(imageNetworkPath), // network image
```